# Is there one website that contains all relevant DevOps news and gets updated on a daily basis?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, cloud, elastic

I am looking for some DevOps news channel like https://nos.nl/teletekst#101 that shows the headlines of the Dutch news. I am aware of https://tweakers.net/ and github.com, but this does not contain all interesting news on one page.

Basically, I would like to receive updates regarding security, features, bugs about several products, e.g. k8s, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu, cloud, AWS, GCP, Azure, centos.

Comment: It doesn't quite match your requirements, so I'll post it as a comment rather than an answer, but Devops Weekly is a weekly email of interesting articles. You can sign up at https://www.devopsweekly.com/ and it is sent out every Sunday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a protocol for this: [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS), Rich Site Summary. Technically, there are 3 protocols RSS, RSS2 and Atom, but most readers support all of them, and many servers mix RSS and RSS2 features.

First, choose your RSS reader, from:

- browser add-ons like [Feedbro](https://nodetics.com/feedbro/),
- centralized aggregators like [Feedly](https://feedly.com/i/welcome) and [FeedReader](http://www.feedreader.com/),
- stand-alone applications like [RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/)
- mail clients like [Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-subscribe-news-feeds-and-blogs).

Second, choose the sources you care about and subscribe to them - you're the curator and most news websites publish RSS feeds. Many don't even know about it, as CMSs like Wordpress sometimes publish an RSS feed by default. I wouldn't be surprised if it had something to do with SEO... Soon, you'll have an OPML list of your favourites.

From your question:

- https://kubernetes.io/feed.xml
- https://www.docker.com/blog/feed/
- https://ubuntu.com/blog/feed
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/feed/
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/feed/
- https://cloudblog.withgoogle.com/products/devops-sre/rss
- https://blog.centos.org/feed/
- https://github.blog/feed/

And a few personal recommendations:

- https://www.theregister.co.uk/devops/headlines.atom
- http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/security
- https://stackoverflow.blog//feed
- https://xkcd.com/rss.xml
- https://www.theregister.co.uk/data_centre/bofh/headlines.atom

Many readers will have an option to search for a feeds on a website, which simplifies the search.

Comment: I have evaluated the option and I like `RSSOwl`. Once RSSOwl was started, an error occurred that could be solved by reading [this](https://superuser.com/a/783910/313985).

Comment: Nowadays I use [informado](https://github.com/030/informado) instead of RSSOwl or RSSOwlnix.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not 100% comprehensive, but

[DevOps.com](https://devops.com/)

might fit the bill?

Comment: Ok I will use this page as a homepage for a week and let you know

Answer (score 2):

I've had good success with DZone: https://dzone.com/devops-tutorials-tools-news.  This is a nice mix of articles, tutorials, and various publications.

For Docker specific updates/news I follow: https://www.docker.com/blog/

Finally, for specific cloud platforms each one seems to have their own community blogers that post updates.  For example:

1. Amazon - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/
2. Microsoft - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/
3. Google - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/devops-sre

Answer (score 1):

There is https://www.infoq.com/devops/ which is a good news feed. I get the newsletter and it is a good overview of trends, etc.

I also check https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/ regularly, but that is AWS specific of course.

Answer (score 1):

I realize these cover much broader ground, but I see lots of useful DevOps-related stories on https://slashdot.org/ and [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/).  I also have created saved searches in Google News.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add https://opensource.com/ (from Redhat) and the O"reilly Newsletter related to Infrastructure and Ops : https://conferences.oreilly.com/infrastructure-ops/io-ca

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a fan of DZone. Another good place is [DevOps.com](https://devops.com/) Also, the [Sonatype blog](https://blog.sonatype.com/) and [All Day DevOps](https://www.alldaydevops.com/blog) regularly feature DevOps news, too [disclosure, I contribute to all of these]